# How to use sample from AR_track_ALVAR

Tags: ros, cmake, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to run the sample "sampleTrack.cpp". When the program is running it is not able to open the camera because it need to use highgui plugin.
So I added Cmakelists.txt from platform to the main Cmakelist with add_subdirectory(src/platform) but when doing my catkin_make, i'm encountering an issue :

```
CMake Error at ar_track_alvar/src/platform/CMakeLists.txt:62 (add_library): Cannot find source file: Capture.h Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp  .hxx .in .txx
```

It can't find headers even if they are in the good directory.
I think there is an easy way to use those samples but there is not mutch ALVAR documentation so I Have no idea how to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213654/how-to-use-sample-from-ar_track_alvar/) by [LaF](https://answers.ros.org/users/23166/laf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want a simple example of the ALVAR tracking bridge in ROS you can [check this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/203207/how-to-use-ar_track_alvar-for-detecting-markers-using-kinect/#203234). Or directly the examples on [this repo](https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar/blob/hydro-devel/launch/pr2_indiv.launch).

If you want to use the original ALVAR library. From what you say all you're missing is highgui in you package. So adding a `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED components core highgui)` to you cmakelist should do the job.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0